# How to implement subqueries in Symfony2 with Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder, doctrine-query

I need to count the number of items returned in the subquery. If I write the subquery how DQL - all good, but if I try to build a query via QueryBuilder - I get an error.

Subquery DQL:

```
$qb3 = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select('COUNT(c.id)')
            ->where('c.id IN (SELECT cl.id FROM Acme\AppBundle\Entity\ClassC cl INNER JOIN Acme\AppBundle\Entity\ClassP p WHERE p.var1 = :var1 AND p.var2 = cl.id GROUP BY cl.id)')
            ->setParameter('var1', $var);
```

Subquery via QueryBuilder:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
$qb->select('COUNT(c.id)')
   ->where(
       $qb->expr()->in(
           'c.id',
           $this->createQueryBuilder('cl')
                ->select('cl.id')
                ->innerJoin('Acme\AppBundle\Entity\ClassP', 'p')
                ->where('p.var1 = :var1')
                ->setParameter('var1', $var)
                ->andWhere('p.var2 = cl.id')
                ->groupBy('cl.id')
                ->getDQL()
     )
 );
```

Both versions return the same DQL.

Error:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1VwW.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to move `setParameter()` to main level of query.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
$qb->select('COUNT(c.id)')
->where(
   $qb->expr()->in(
       'c.id',
       $this->createQueryBuilder('cl')
            ->select('cl.id')
            ->innerJoin('Acme\AppBundle\Entity\ClassP', 'p')
            ->where('p.var1 = :var1')
            ->andWhere('p.var2 = cl.id')
            ->groupBy('cl.id')
            ->getDQL()
 )
)
->setParameter('var1', $var);
```